# Detect Smartcard removal in J2ME (JSR257)?

Tags: java-me, smartcard, midlet, jsr257, contactless-smartcard

I'm using the J2ME contactless API ([JSR257](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=257) - `javax.microedition.contactless.*`) to read smartcards on a Nokia phone. The following code works just fine and the `targetDetected` method is called as expected when I put a card on the phone:

```
DiscoveryManager dm = DiscoveryManager.getInstance();
dm.addTargetListener(this, TargetType.ISO14443_CARD);

public void targetDetected(TargetProperties[] tps) {
   logger.log("found card!");
}
```

However, I'm wondering if there is any way to get a callback when the card is removed? Or is the only way to check if the card has been removed to `try` and open or read from a connection and `catch` the appropriate exceptions?